# Missing data after adding the time range

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization

I've been struggling for hours, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Namely, my goal is to show a line graph with the number of infected people in a certain unit of time, where the y axis would show the number of infected and the x axis the time range.
This is what the graph should look like:

[image: Line Graph]

However, after adding the time range to the x-axis, the line related to the number of infected people in a unit of time is no longer displayed
This is what the graph look like:

[image: Line Graph]

The path for svg seems to be made:

[image: Chrome Dev Tools]

I appreciate any help..

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import {
  select,
  line,
  curveCardinal,
  scaleLinear,
  max,
  scaleTime,
  axisBottom,
  axisLeft,
  extent,
} from "d3";

const ChartFirstCase = () => {
  const fromFirstDayData = useSelector((state) => state.fromFirstDayData);
  const { allData } = fromFirstDayData;

  const cases = allData ? allData.map((data) => data.Cases) : [];
  const dates = allData ? allData.map((data) => data.Dates) : [];

  const getDate = (dateValue) => {
    const date = dateValue;
    return new Date(date);
  };

  const days = extent(dates);
  const minDate = getDate(days[0]);
  const maxDate = getDate(days[1]);

  const sorting = (a, b) => a - b;
  cases.sort(sorting);

  const svgRef = useRef();
  const svgHeight = 200;
  const svgWidth = 400;

  useEffect(() => {
    const svg = select(svgRef.current);

    const maxProp = allData
      ? max(allData.map((broj) => broj.Cases))
      : "";

    const xScale = scaleTime().domain([minDate, maxDate]).range([0, 400]);
    const yScale = scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, maxProp + 50000])
      .range([200, 0]);

    const xAxis = axisBottom(xScale).ticks(5);
    const yAxis = axisLeft(yScale).ticks(5);

    svg.select(".x-axis").style("transform", "translateY(200px)").call(xAxis);
    svg.select(".y-axis").call(yAxis);

    const casesLine = line()
      .x((value, index) => xScale(index))
      .y(yScale)
      .curve(curveCardinal);

    svg
      .selectAll(".line")
      .data([cases])
      .join("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", casesLine)
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke", "red");
  }, [cases, allData, minDate, maxDate]);

  return (
    <div className="chartsBox">
      <div className="chartBox">
        <svg width={svgWidth} height={svgHeight} ref={svgRef}>
          <g className="x-axis" />
          <g className="y-axis" />
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ChartFirstCase;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path is there, as you can see, but the x coordinates are completely off. The probable reason is that you're using `d3.extent` on *strings*. When you do that, `10` comes before `9`.

Thus, convert everything to date objects from the beginning, and drop that `getDate` function:

```
const dates = allData ? allData.map((data) => new Date(data.Dates)) : [];
```

However, that's not enough, because you're passing only `cases` as the data, and passing the indices of each object to the x scale:

```
const casesLine = line()
  .x((value, index) => xScale(index))
  .y(yScale)
  .curve(curveCardinal);
```

Instead of that, use a data array that contains *both dates and cases* and change your line generator accordingly. For instance:

```
const casesLine = line()
  .x((value) => xScale(value.date))
  .y((value) => yScale(value.case))
  .curve(curveCardinal);
```

Comment: After adding the code you listed above, using the d3 min and max functions I found the smallest date and the largest.
   // const minDay = min (dates.map (day) => day));
   // const maxDay = max (dates.map (day) => day));
console.log (minDay, maxDay) now prints:
   // Wed Feb 26 2020 08:00:00 GMT + 0100 (Central European Standard Time)
  // Sun Mar 14 2021 11:52:00 GMT + 0100 (Central European Standard Time)

Is that what it should look like?
After placing min and max in domain, the graph remains the same

Comment: Please have a look at what I said about the data and the line generator. Also, these are just tips for pointing you to the right direction, you'll have to refactor your code yourself.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I didn't see you editing the post. And exactly that edited part was important. I extracted the data as you said, to be all cases and dates together. Sorted the data from the first day until today and boom, worked like magic.
Thank you so much, you saved me from struggling!